# How can I predeclare an array?

Tags: java, arrays, jpanel

I don't know if this is possible, but I am trying to make a JPanel with a drop down list.  One of the parameters takes an array of options, so I have to use an array, not a list.

I am doing this right now:

```
        //if they have enough gold to buy 5
        if(totalGold >= 25){
            Object[] possibilities = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
        }
        //if they have between 20 and 24 gold
        else if(totalGold >= 20 && totalGold < 25){
            Object[] possibilities = {1, 2, 3, 4};
        }
        //if Player has between 15 and 19 gold
        else if(totalGold >=15 && totalGold < 19){
            Object[] possibilities = {1, 2, 3};
        }
        //if Player has between 10 and 14 gold
        else if(totalGold >= 10 && totalGold <14){
            Object[] possibilities = {1, 2};
        }
        //if Player has between 5 and 9 gold
        else if(totalGold >= 5 && totalGold < 9){
            Object[] possibilities = {1};
        }
```

Unfortunately the possibilities variable is out of scope and I am unable to use this variable.  I would like to be able to say something like:

```
Object[] possibilities;
```

and then define what the array is later but I don't seem to be able to do that.

Is there a way to be able to change what the possibilities array contains based on the value of totalGold?

Thanks!

Comment: What's making it seem like you can't do that?  It should be fine to declare `possibilities` outside of your `if` block, as long as it is guaranteed to be assigned a value (i.e., add an `else` that will run if all the other conditions fail).

Comment: @FiveNine You cannot use 'array constants' in assignment operations. Only when declaring the array var.

Comment: @ColinD Right, it has to be `possibilities = new Object[]{1, 2..}`.  My point was that you can certainly declare `possibilities` outside of the `if` block and assign it a value later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Notice the pattern between the `totalGold` and the array size. The size is same as `totalGold % 5` for `totalGold <= 24`, while for any greater value, the size is just `5`.

You can make use of that:

```
int arraySize = Math.min(totalGold % 5, 5);

// Why Object[]?
int[] possibilities = new int[arraySize];

for (int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++) {
    possibilities[i] = i + 1;
}
```

This works because the value in your array is in sequence starting from `1`.

Comment: Thank you!  I hadn't even thought of doing something like this.  I'm using object just because that's what the example from Oracle was using.

Answer (score 1):

Declare your 'possibilities' before hand and then just assign the correct one in your if statements.

```
       Object[] possibilities1 = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
       Object[] possibilities2 = {1, 2, 3, 4};
       Object[] possibilities3 = {1, 2, 3 };
       Object[] possibilities4 = {1, 2};
       Object[] possibilities5 = {1};

       Object[] possibilities;

       //if they have enough gold to buy 5
        if(totalGold >= 25){
            possibilities = possibilities1;
        }
        //if they have between 20 and 24 gold
        else if(totalGold >= 20 && totalGold < 25){
            possibilities = possibilities2;
        }
        //if Player has between 15 and 19 gold
        else if(totalGold >=15 && totalGold < 19){
           possibilities = possibilities3;
        }
        //if Player has between 10 and 14 gold
        else if(totalGold >= 10 && totalGold <14){
            possibilities = possibilities4;
        }
        //if Player has between 5 and 9 gold
        else if(totalGold >= 5 && totalGold < 9){
            possibilities = possibilities5;
        }
```

However, if you can generate the array and its contents dynamically as [Rohit Jain suggests in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22204733/1311351), you should probably pursue such an approach.

Comment: Thanks!  It's been so long since I've had to use an array instead of a list that I have forgotten everything that I could do with one

Answer (score 0):

Rohit Jain's answer is the way to go.  But I'll address your actual question to explain what's going on.

I'm guessing you tried something like this:

```
Object[] possibilities;

//if they have enough gold to buy 5
if(totalGold >= 25){
    possibilities = new Object[]{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}; // needs to have 'new Object[]'
}
//if they have between 20 and 24 gold
else if(totalGold >= 20 && totalGold < 25){
    possibilities = new Object[]{1, 2, 3, 4};
}
//if Player has between 15 and 19 gold
else if(totalGold >=15 && totalGold < 19){
    possibilities = new Object[]{1, 2, 3};
}
//if Player has between 10 and 14 gold
else if(totalGold >= 10 && totalGold <14){
    possibilities = new Object[]{1, 2};
}
//if Player has between 5 and 9 gold
else if(totalGold >= 5 && totalGold < 9){
    possibilities = new Object[]{1};
}

doSomethingWithPossibilities(possibilities);
```

You probably got an error that `possibilities` might not have been initialized, which is true.  What is `possibilities` if `totalGold` is `3`?

The solution is to add an `else` to make sure that no matter how the `if/else if/else` evaluates, `possibilities` always ends up with a value (or the method exits with an exception).

```
Object[] possibilities;

//if they have enough gold to buy 5
if(totalGold >= 25){
    possibilities = new Object[]{1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
}

[snip]

//if Player has between 5 and 9 gold
else if(totalGold >= 5 && totalGold < 9){
    possibilities = new Object[]{1};
}
else {
    possibilities = new Object[]; //or null, or throw exception, or...
}

doSomethingWithPossibilities(possibilities);
```